# Moving IF statement from Crystal Reports to SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, crystal-reports

Background:  I have an IF statement from Crystal Reports XI and would like to transfer/translate it to SQL Server Management Studio 2012 as a CASE statement.  I understand IF/CASE statements, but I'm having trouble understanding this one- one section in particular.  I looked everywhere on this site and the web and could not find a similar situation.

Question:  I want to take the IF statement below and change the format to run correctly in SQL Server Management Studio 2012.  The part I do not understand are the comma’s after tblLin.QtyShipped.  To me that seems like an extra argument is trying to be performed…maybe like a SUMIF?  The IF statement from Crystal is a “Formula Field”.

This is the original code from Crystal Reports:

```
IF {tblProd.UnitsInABox} > 0
THEN Sum {tblLin.QtyShipped}, ({tblProd.ProdNumb}/{tblProd_1.Servings})
ELSE Sum {tblLin.QtyShipped}, ({tblProd.ProdNumb})/{tbl.WProd.MstrQuantity})
END AS QtyShipped
```

This is what I've got for (SQL Server Management Studio) which is wrong, but showing effort.

```
CASE
WHEN (tblProd.UnitsInABox) > 0
THEN Sum(tblLin.QtyShipped), (tblProd.ProdNumb/tblProd_1.Servings)
ELSE Sum(tblLin.QtyShipped), (tblProd.ProdNumb/tbl.WProd.MstrQuantity)
END AS QtyShipped
```

Thank you and please let me know if I didn't follow any specific rules for posting.

Comment: What are you trying to take the sum of?

Comment: Sean Lange -  trying to take the sum of tblLin.QtyShipped.

Comment: ok...but if you want the sum of that column what is the calculation?

Comment: sorry, I don't understand what you mean by calculation.  The report has a parameter for a date range, though.  When you enter the date range it takes the total quantity shipped for each product (which I would think be the SUM for tblLin.QtyShipped), for that time period.  Maybe the IF statement from Crystal has been or is incorrect to begin with.

Comment: SUM receives 1 and only 1 column. You also have a second value inside your case expression but I have no idea what that means.

Comment: That makes sense...thank you Sean.  Once (if) I figure out who created the report, I will follow up with what he/she was trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

You can't handle two columns at the same time, so you have to take the first column out of the case statement.

```
Sum(tblLin.QtyShipped) AS QtyShipped
,CASE
WHEN (tblProd.UnitsInABox) > 0
THEN (tblProd.ProdNumb/tblProd_1.Servings)
ELSE (tblProd.ProdNumb/tbl.WProd.MstrQuantity)
END
```

Comment: I learned that the IF statement was trying to sum at the product level, and then divide by the product's number of servings.  This answer best suits what I needed and solved the problem. thank you.